# Duplicate components of the same type in react don't behave as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a sorting component that has its own array. I am passing an array to both components and updating the sorting components with my random array that I passed as props. I am trying to display two sorting components on the same page to allow race between them using sorting algorithms, I tried to render the two sorting components with each one having its own button and array but when I try to sort one of them the other components array gets sorted to !! I expected that each component is not related to the sibling components.

```
class MainPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            array: [],
            temp: [1, 2]

        };
        this.child = React.createRef();
    }
    // generating the random numbers
    randomNumber(min, max) {
        min = Math.ceil(min);
        max = Math.floor(max);
        let result = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
        return result;
    }
    async componentDidMount() {
        await this.resetTheArray();
        console.log("yes its me ", this.state)
    }
    resetTheArray() {
        const temp = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            temp.push(this.randomNumber(5, 750));
        }
        // must use this method to concatinate the new element to the array inside the state
        this.setState({ array: temp });
    }
    onClick = () => {
        this.child.current.fillArray();
        console.log("yes")
    }
    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <NavBar ></NavBar>
                {this.state.temp.map((e) => (<Sorting key={`{e}`} id={e} array={this.state.array} />))}
                <button onClick={this.onClick}>click here</button>
            </div >
        )
    }

}

export default MainPage;
```

/////////

```
class sorting extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      array: [],
      bars: NumberOfBars,
      firstSelection: "Insertion",
      btn: false,
      dual: true,
    };
    this.fillArray = this.fillArray.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    const { array } = this.state;
    console.log(this.state);
    console.log("the key ", this.props.id);
    return (
      <Container>
        <div className="theContainer">
          {array.map((value, idx) => (
            <div
              className={"theBar " + this.props.id}
              key={idx}
              style={{ height: `${value}px` }}
            ></div>
          ))}
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.bubbleSort}>sort</button>
        <button onClick={this.fillArray}>reset</button>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to add a key to each sorting component but react doesn't distinguish between them!!

Answer (score 0):

An array is a pointer in memory, so you're referencing the same array in both of your components. You need to a create a new array for each one.

```js
{this.state.temp.map((e) => (<Sorting key={`{e}`} id={e} array={[...this.state.array]} />))}
```

The [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) creates a new array, so this should work.

Comment: That is precisely what I wanted,  thank you !!!!